# Earliest moment for interrupted wedding to be considered binding?

Tags: halacha, wedding, murder

A Jewish marriage takes place but the ceremony is, Hashem forbid, interrupted by a terrorist's bullet. One of the couple dies.  How far must the ceremony have gone for the bereaved to be considered a widow or widower for uniting the two families in defiance of the murderer's will?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the interesting question (+1)! Chas v'chalila we ever have to deal with it, but it's still an interesting thought experiment.

Comment: Well @Scimonster the simple answer would be when he has given the ring. Before that she is not married.

Comment: I don't understand the standard of marriage we're working with. The families can be as united as they want. Honestly, for almost all halachic purposes it's much more convenient if they weren't married.

Comment: Let's make the question a bit less morbid --  suppose the bride's long-lost lover reappears mid-wedding and she runs away with him. *Mawwiage. Mawwiage is what bwings us togethew today. Mawwiage, that bwessed awwangement, that dweam within a dweam!*

Answer (score 6):

**From the moment the bride receives the ring** (or anything else of value) from the groom after he declares הֲרֵי אַתְּ מְקֻדֶּשֶׁת לִי in the presence of 2 Kosher witnesses, they are married, and the families are Halachically united:

- She now requires a Get to get married to anybody else
- Their families may no longer marry each other's close relatives

However, until they complete the Chuppa ceremony (to be defined, as it depends on community custom):

- They may not live together
- He is not responsible to feed her (for the first 12 months)
- He does not inherit her
- He is not responsible to pay for her burial
- If he's a Cohen he can't become Tameh - defiled - for her
- They do not become an Avel (mourner) for each other

Sources:
Shulchan Aruch, Even Ha'Ezer 54 - סימן נה - דין ארוסה לענין מזונות וקבורה וירשה.

> **א:** הָאֲרוּסָה, אֲסוּרָה לְבַעֲלָהּ מִדִּבְרֵי סוֹפְרִים, כָּל זְמַן שֶׁהִיא בְּבֵית אָבִיהָ; וְהַבָּא עַל אֲרוּסָתוֹ בְּבֵית חָמִיו, מַכִּין אוֹתוֹ מַכַּת מַרְדּוּת‏
>
> **ד:** אֵין הָאָרוּס חַיָּב בִּמְזוֹנוֹת אֲרוּסָתוֹ‏
>
> **ה:** אֲרוּסָה שֶׁמֵּתָה, אִם הָיָה הָאָרוּס כֹּהֵן, אֵינוֹ מִטַּמֵּא לָהּ. וְאִם מֵת הוּא, אֵינָהּ חַיֶּבֶת  לִטַּמֵּא לוֹ, וְאֵינוֹ יוֹרְשָׁהּ, וְאֵינוֹ חַיָּב בִּקְבוּרָתָהּ, אֶלָּא אָבִיהָ יוֹרְשָׁהּ וְאָבִיהָ קוֹבְרָהּ‏

The last Halacha comes from Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De'ah 374:4 - סימן שעד - טמאת כהן למת מצוה, לנשיא ולרבו, ועל איזה מת מתאבלין

> **ד:** כָּל הַקְּרוֹבִים שֶׁהַכֹּהֵן מִטָּמֵא לָהֶם, שֶׁהֵם: אָבִיו, וְאִמּוֹ, וּבְנוֹ, וּבִתּוֹ, וְאָחִיו, וַאֲחוֹתוֹ מֵאָבִיו הַבְּתוּלָה, וְאִשְׁתּוֹ, מִתְאַבְּלִים עֲלֵיהֶם. וְעוֹד הוֹסִיפוּ עֲלֵיהֶם: אָחִיו מֵאִמּוֹ, וַאֲחוֹתוֹ מֵאִמּוֹ, בֵּין בְּתוּלָה בֵּין נְשׂוּאָה, וַאֲחוֹתוֹ נְשׂוּאָה מֵאָבִיו, שֶׁמִּתְאַבְּלִים עֲלֵיהֶם אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵין כֹּהֵן מִטָּמֵא לָהֶם. וּכְשֵׁם שֶׁהוּא מִתְאַבֵּל עַל אִשְׁתּוֹ, כָּךְ הִיא מִתְאַבֶּלֶת עָלָיו. וְדַוְקָא אִשְׁתּוֹ כְּשֵׁרָה וּנְשׂוּאָה, אֲבָל פְּסוּלָה אוֹ אֲרוּסָה, לֹא. ‏